# Output result not changing when I choose input values in dropdown menu

Tags: shiny

I have a problem with the shiny app in that the plots does not change when I choose different input values in the app. In my example  I want to choose different "miRNA" resulting in a different survival-plot

[image: Output]

Here is my app:

```
library(dplyr) 
require(survminer)
library(tidyverse)
require(reshape2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
require(survival)
```

example data:

```
 df.miRNA.cpm <-     structure(list(`86` = c(5.57979757386892, 17.0240095264258, 4.28380151026145, 
13.0457611762755, 12.5531123449841), `175` = c(5.21619202802748, 
15.2849097474841, 2.46719979911461, 10.879496005461, 9.66416497290915
), `217` = c(5.42796072966512, 17.1413407297933, 5.15230233060323, 
12.2646127361351, 12.1031024927547), `394` = c(-1.1390337316217, 
15.1021660424984, 4.63168157763046, 11.1299079134792, 9.55572588729967
), `444` = c(5.06134249676025, 14.5442494311861, -0.399445049232868, 
7.45775961504073, 9.92629675808998)), row.names = c("hsa_let_7a_3p", 
"hsa_let_7a_5p", "hsa_let_7b_3p", "hsa_let_7b_5p", "hsa_let_7c_5p"
), class = "data.frame")

df.miRNA.cpm$miRNA <- rownames(df.miRNA.cpm)


  ss.survival.shiny.miRNA.miRNA <-   structure(list(ID = c("86", "175", "217", "394", "444"), TimeDiff = c(71.0416666666667, 
601.958333333333, 1130, 1393, 117.041666666667), Status = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Joint the two example data frames:

```
 data_prep.miRNA <- df.miRNA.cpm %>% 
tidyr::pivot_longer(-miRNA, names_to = "ID") %>% 
left_join(ss.survival.shiny.miRNA.miRNA)
```

Example of the joined data:

```
 > data_prep.miRNA
# A tibble: 153,033 x 5
   miRNA         ID     value TimeDiff Status
   <chr>         <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <int>
 1 hsa_let_7a_3p 86     5.58      71.0      1
 2 hsa_let_7a_3p 175    5.22     602.       1
 3 hsa_let_7a_3p 217    5.43    1130        0
 4 hsa_let_7a_3p 394   -1.14    1393        0
 5 hsa_let_7a_3p 444    5.06     117.       1
 6 hsa_let_7a_3p 618    4.37    1508        0
 7 hsa_let_7a_3p 640    2.46    1409        0
 8 hsa_let_7a_3p 829    0.435    919.       0
 9 hsa_let_7a_3p 851   -1.36     976.       0
10 hsa_let_7a_3p 998    3.87    1196.       0
# … with 153,023 more rows
```

Shiny:

```
ui.miRNA <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("MicroRNA", "miRNA", choices = unique(data_prep.miRNA$miRNA)),

  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(data_prep.miRNA, miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA)
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
        survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value, quantile(value, probs = c(0, .4, .8)), include.lowest=TRUE),data = data_selected())

    ggsurvplot(fitSurv)
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui.miRNA, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the output of `survfit` to `fitSurv`:

```
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    fitSurv <- survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value, quantile(value, probs = c(0, .4, .8)), include.lowest=TRUE),data = data_selected())
    ggsurvplot(fitSurv)
  })
```

Comment: Gives this: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
[31mx[39m object 'input' not found
[34mℹ[39m Input `..1` is `miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA`.

Comment: @user2300940 This works for me. What is this `..1`? And what is `[31mx[39m`?